# Set Magento 2 store Domain name

Tags: magento2, domain

I have a Magento 2 store in Amazon cloud and I wanted to set a domain name.
I set the A record in my domain name registrar as in the picture.

[image]
when I type my **URL**, it forwards me to the shop but I see the IP address instead of Domain name.

[image]

Comment: after adding domain name in amazon cloud , have you change urls in magento database `core_config_data` table ?

Comment: @ManthanDave That was easy and fast, thank you, could you answer it so I mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its redirecting because you have replaced Domain with IP address in Amazon Cloud , But you forgot to replace this in Magento `core_config_table`.

> **So go to your magento  database , open core_config_data and add domain in base_url "web/unsecure/base_url" AND "web/secure/base_url"**
>   **it will works for you.**

Comment: @bourax - Happy to help , Keep Helping :)